# rspamd won't start (code=killed, signal=SEGV) on Pi 4 (11 64-bit)

Tags: 64-bit

I've been tring to set up rspamd on a 4GB Pi 4, running an uptodate 64-bit Raspberry OS 11. After a successful install, running "systemctl status rspamd.service" displays:

```
 rspamd.service - rapid spam filtering system
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rspamd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: signal) since Mon 2022-03-28 12:20:39 BST; 10s ago
   Docs: https://rspamd.com/doc/
Process: 46649 ExecStart=/usr/bin/rspamd -c /etc/rspamd/rspamd.conf -f
 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
 Main PID: 46649 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
    CPU: 48ms

 Mar 28 12:20:39 hallpi systemd[1]: rspamd.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
 Mar 28 12:20:39 hallpi systemd[1]: rspamd.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

I've done some searching, and I'm prerty sure this is because I'm running a 64-bit OS, but I can't find any solutions, or anyone else with the same issue on a Raspberry Pi.

Has anyone here come across this, or found a fix?

Comment: Where did you get rspamd from? how did you install it? For what kind of architecture has your app been compiled? Exactly which OS do you run (there are several 64-bit OSs)? ...

Comment: I just did "sudo apt install rspamd". I'm using "Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit) Lite 11" (which I personally still call Raspbian because that was a better name).

Answer (score 1):

In the end I decided to install rspamd from source because I couldn't get the  apt package to work on 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS.

Here's what I did (I'm sure it could be done better, but it worked):

```
cd ~
sudo apt install rspamd
mkdir rspamdconfig
sudo mv /etc/rspamd/* rspamdconfig/rspamd
sudo apt purge rspamd
sudo apt autopurge
sudo rm -r /etc/rspamd/

mkdir rspamd.build
cd rspamd.build
git clone --recursive https://github.com/rspamd/rspamd.git
mkdir rspamd.build
cd rspamd.build

sudo apt install cmake ragel pkg-config liblua5.1-dev libglib2.0-dev libsqlite3-dev libicu-dev libmagic-dev libssl-dev redis libsodium-dev lua5.4

nano ../rspamd/CMakeLists.txt
```

Change:

OPTION(WANT_SYSTEMD_UNITS  "Install systemd unit files on Linux [default: OFF]" OFF)

to

OPTION(WANT_SYSTEMD_UNITS  "Install systemd unit files on Linux [default: OFF]" ON)

```
cmake ../rspamd -DENABLE_LUAJIT=OFF
make -j8
sudo make install

sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/rspamadm-3.3 /usr/bin/rspamadm-3.3
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/rspamadm-3.3 /usr/bin/rspamadm
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/rspamc-3.3 /usr/bin/rspamc-3.3
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/rspamc-3.3 /usr/bin/rspamc
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/rspamd-3.3 /usr/bin/rspamd-3.3
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/rspamd-3.3 /usr/bin/rspamd
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/rspamd_stats /usr/bin/rspamd_stats

sudo mkdir /etc/rspamd
sudo mv rspamdconfig/rspamd/* /etc/rspamd/
sudo chown -R root:root /etc/rspamd/

sudo mkdir /var/log/rspamd/
sudo touch /var/log/rspamd/rspamd.log
sudo chown -R _rspamd:_rspamd /var/log/rspamd/

sudo systemctl start rspamd.service
sudo systemctl enable rspamd.service
systemctl status rspamd.service
cd ~
rm -rf rspamd.build/
rm -rf rspamdconfig/
```