# Is there a usable rspamd package anywhere for Raspberry Pi Bullseye 64 bit?

Tags: mail-server

Creating a mail server on Raspberry Pi with 64 bit OS, the rspamd package from the repository crashes, as described at [rspamd won't start (code=killed, signal=SEGV) on Pi 4 (11 64-bit)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/136785/rspamd-wont-start-code-killed-signal-segv-on-pi-4-11-64-bit).

It is version 2.7 but that would be acceptable if it would work. I don't want to go to 32 bit because of the reduced memory availability (on 8gb Pi). Version 3 would be better.

Is there a ready build .deb package anywhere? Or a repo that contains one?

Comment: Did you try installing from source, like in the question you linked to?

Comment: Thanks, but no. I’m not happy about installing development tools and running builds on a critical server. And I’ve found the rspamd instructions for creating a .deb package to be defective in the past.